# Centering Perspective Camera on two objects by panning

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, unityscript

In Unity, I have a perspective camera, and I've got two transforms in my scene that I want the camera to perfectly center on screen.  The camera will pan left/right/up/down to the appropriate location.

So far my approach has been to convert the transform positions to screen positions using `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`, and taking their average to find the screen midpoint.  From there, I know I want to pan the camera a certain number of units toward that midpoint.  What I'm having trouble with is figuring out the formula for deciding how much to pan (or, maybe this isn't even the preferred way to determine this).

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is great. Let me expand the idea.

[image]

So this is your screen :D. Blue circle is where you want your objects to be. There are two scenarios. We will use green dots as an example of zooming scenario. Then red dots for panning scenario.

The trick is, you want to keep the dots as close as possible to **circumference** of blue circle.

Let's say you get red dots as your objects' screen position. You have to shift them towards the center. Let's calculate `CenterOfDots`. Then calculate it's difference to `CenterOfBlueCircle`. That's **how much pan you need *in screen coordinates***.

So you have calculated the pan. Now you want to know how much you need to zoom. Let's say you get green dots this time. Calculate `DistanceBetweenDots` and compare it to `DiameterOfBlueCircle`. You want them to be the same. So their difference is **how much zoom you need *in screen coordinates***.

There comes the tricky part. Now you know how much to pan and zoom in screen space. But you need to move the camera in world space. Trying to solve it using geometry magic is fine. But I hate headache :D

So instead, I would iteratively shift my camera using the data I calculated above. Just shift the camera in it's local x-y axes towards `HowMuchPan`, multiplied by a manually given coefficient `PanSpeed`. This will give a smooth transition to the camera. Same is for the zoom. This time you shift the camera in it's local z axis using `HowMuchZoom` multiplied by your manually given coefficient `ZoomSpeed`.

Hope it helps. Have fun :)

Comment: love the graphic :)

my initial approach as pretty similar to yours - figure out which direction to pan, then pan a certain amount. next, check to see if we've panned too far.  if we have, you can easily calculate a percentage to use to pan back to the 'correct' position.  for the most part this works, but when adding some intelligent zooming code, it looked like it would sometimes produce some unwanted jitter.

Comment: i did figure out the mathy approach which i'll list as an answer. site is telling me it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the mathy approach!

for panning, you want to figure out the average screen position of your objects (i.e. the middle). then you want to generate a couple world points  against an arbitrary plane some distance away from the camera. the difference between these points is how much to pan the camera

```
center=Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Screen.width*0.5f, Screen.height*0.5f, 10f)
mid=Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(averageScreenPoint.x, averageScreenPoint.y, 10f)
Camera.transform.Translate(mid-center)
```

zooming is a bit more complicated, but very similar to the panning approach. you want to use Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint against an arbitrary plane, but you want to do this for 4 points, which will help you figure out a scale to apply to your camera's z position. psuedocode -

```
screenMin = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(0f,0f,10f);
screenMax = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Screen.width,Screen.height,10f);
objMin = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosMin.x, screenPosMin.y, 10f);
objMax = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosMax.x, screenPosMax.y, 10f);
screenDiff = screenMax-screenMin;
objDiff = objMax-objMin;
Vector3 scale = new Vector3(objDiff.x/screenDiff.x, objDiff.y/screenDiff.y, 0f);
ratio = scale.x < scale.y ? scale.y : scale.x;// pick the one that best puts fits on screen.
Camera.localPosition.z = Mathf.Min(ZoomMin, Camera.localPosition.z*ratio);
```